# How to share a link of my app from app in iOS(swiftui)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to have a button in my app that will allow the user to send a link of the same app via message, whatsApp, or whatever.

Is that possible ? I haven't found any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) to display the standard share dialog.  Since this is a `UIViewController` you will need to wrap it in a [`UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable) to use it with SwiftUI.

The item you share will be a `URL` instance that contains the App Store link to your app.